# Old Edge - how to create "image" object?

Tags: javascript, image, svg, microsoft-edge

I have following sample of code:

```
const newImageNode = document.createElement("image");
const imageHrefAttribute = document.createAttribute("href");
imageHrefAttribute.value = `${iconName}.svg`;
newImageNode.attributes.setNamedItem(imageHrefAttribute);


$(this).empty().append(newImageNode);
$(this).html($(this).html());
```

`this` - G in SVG.

I use it to attach image object to SVG code. It works perfectly for the Chrome, but for some reason old Edge (I mean non-Chromium based) renders it as `img` what causes that my attached images are not visible.

Can anyone suggest how to avoid this problem?

Comment: `insertAdjacentHTML` should work on edge

Comment: You need to set the NameSpace of your element so it's an SVGElement. Failing to do so, you just create an [HTML <image> element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/image). Note that it used to be the same for `href` attribute (`setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', \`${iconName}.svg\`)`), though since SVG2 it's not required anymore (old IE don't support SVG2, so there you still need it).

Answer (score 0):

You can directly replace the html code in `<g>` with `<image>` element to show the image. Please also remember to give the image a `height` and a `width` which is necessary in Edge Legacy:

```
$("#container").html(`<image href="${iconName}.svg" width="50" height="50"></image>`);
```

Sample code:

```js
$("#container").html('<image href="https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg" width="50" height="50"></image>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g id="container">
           <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="25" />
           <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="25" />
        </g>
</svg>
```